# WSO bam for aggregating events?

Tags: wso2

I have a real time web analytics problem to address, and I'm wondering if some of the WSO2 products might be an appropriate solution.

An ecommerce web site shows pages of products to a browser user, and the web site vendor wants to collect details of what products were viewed in a list, what products were selected from the list for more info, what products were put into the basket, and what products were actually purchased - all in real time.  I can use web page tagging to generate logging events for the four states (I.e. In list, view detail, in basket, purchased). The web site vendor wants too see results summarized by product and by rolling time band (e.g. Last hour, last 6 hours, last 24 hours, last 72 hours) by the four product states.

As a complete WSO2 newbie I'm hoping somebody can help with some pointers on how to address this.  I've been reading about the BAM module to capture events. Is that a good place to start?  Also can anybody suggest a good in memory data store to hold the event data aggregated by event type and rolling time period?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Yes, BAM is more kind batch processing, monitoring and complex engine and using it you can capture data, process and then present. In architectural point of view, the product states that are changed by the browser user will be captured by the web server and publish to BAM server.

A good point to start is learning about data publishing. Once you define the data [in BAM it is known as stream definition] to be published, you can write a hive script to process it and present. You can pump all data to BAM and then you can use hive script to process and store it in the manner you wanted. Later you can retrieve and present.